# File from assignment has import Haskell stack does not recognize

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-criterion

I got a download file from my University for one of my assignments, it has an `import Criterion.Main` that my version of stack does not recognize

I tried updating my Stack and cabal, added

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
```

to the beginning of my file, and tried running `stack fib2.hs` (the name of the file with the problematic import), but this only got me these error messages:

```
stack: WARNING! Expecting stack options comment at line 1, column 1
stack: WARNING! Missing or unusable Stack options specification
stack: WARNING! Using runghc without any additional Stack options
Executable named sh not found on path: [Path]
```

the file itself had

```
stack --resolver lts-11.10 script --optimize
```

put in there by my uni, but when I try to run this I get another error:

```
Missing: FILE

Usage: stack.exe script [--package PACKAGE] FILE
                    [-- ARGUMENT(S) (e.g. stack script X.hs -- argument(s) to program).]
                    [--compile | --optimize] [--[no-]use-root]
                    [--ghc-options OPTIONS] [--extra-dep PACKAGE-VERSION]
                    [--no-run] [--setup-info-yaml URL]
                    [--snapshot-location-base URL] [--help]

Run a Stack script
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something somewhere is pointing to an `sh` executable. You can see that from the last bit of the error message `Stack options Executable named sh not found on path: [Path]`.  You can also run a script by executing `stack [script_filename]`, which might work or maybe give you another error.

Comment: Your problem seems to have nothing to do with the Criterion import really, this is a deeper setup issue. You should try to first get Stack working with a simple Hello World program.